# Reference for Varopoulos isoperimetric inequality with multiplicity

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, isoperimetric-problems

The Varopoulos isoperimetric inequality for a bounded domain $D$ in a nilpotent group $\Gamma$ of growth $n$ reads
$$
\# D \le \mathrm{const} \cdot (\#\partial D)^{n/(n-1)}
$$

See Ch. 6.E+ in Gromov's work cited below. In the same work (p. 65) they give a (Varopoulos) isoperimetric inequality for a multiple domain (i.e., a domain where we involve multiplicities). The paragraph in question reads as follows, where $\tilde{W}$ is the universal cover of a Carnot group of growth $n$:

> Nevertheless, the presence of high multiplicity enhances the power of the (Varpoulos) isoperimetric inequality in $\tilde{W}$, which reads in our case (compare Ch. 6.E$_+$)
> \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
> \mathrm{vol}_n(\Omega) \le \mathrm{const}\,(\mathrm{vol}_{n-1}(\partial\Omega))^{n/(n-1)} \tag{*}
> \end{equation}
> But if $\Omega$ is a multiple domain given by a map $I : \Omega \to \tilde{W}$ (which can be assumed to be an immersion), and $\mu(w) = card(I^{-1}(w))$ is the multiplicity of $\Omega$ at the points $w \in \Omega_1 = \mathrm{im}_I(\Omega)$, then the oriented volume
> $$
> \mathrm{vol}(\Omega) \stackrel{def}{=}\int_{\Omega}I^*(d\nu_{\tilde{W}})
> $$
> can be bounded in terms of the average multiplicity $\overline{\mu} = (\int_{\Omega} \mu d\nu_{\tilde{W}})/\mathrm{vol}(\Omega_1)$ by
> \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
> \mathrm{vol}(\Omega) \le \mathrm{const}\,\mu^{-1/(n-1)} (\mathrm{vol}(\partial \Omega))^{n/(n-1)}, \tag{**}
> \end{equation}
> as follows by \eqref{eq:1} applied to the subdomains $\Omega_i \subset \Omega_1$ where $\mu \ge i$, for $i = 1,2,\dots$.

I have a few questions with this:

1. In the definition of $\overline{\mu}$, wouldn't we want $\overline{\mu} = (\int_{\Omega_1} \mu d\nu_{\tilde{W}})/\mathrm{vol}(\Omega_1)$? In particular, does $\int_{\Omega} \mu d\nu_{\tilde{W}}$ (as it is currently written) even make sense?
2. In \eqref{eq:2}, shouldn't we have $\overline{\mu}^{-1/(n-1)}$ rather than $\mu^{-1/(n-1)}$? Otherwise, what's the point of introducing $\overline{\mu}$ in the first place?
3. I believe that I understand how to get something like \eqref{eq:2} on each $\Omega_i$ individually, but I don't know how they combine as indicated to result in the total bound on $\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)$. I have been convinced that it likely follows from some analysis inequality, but I don't know exactly how or which one. Any references to the proof of this fact would be much appreciated.

---

***References***

*Gromov, Misha*, Metric structures for Riemannian and non-Riemannian spaces. Transl. from the French by Sean Michael Bates. With appendices by M. Katz, P. Pansu, and S. Semmes. Edited by J. LaFontaine and P. Pansu, Progress in Mathematics (Boston, Mass.). 152. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. xix, 585 p. (1999). [ZBL0953.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0953.53002).